# How to improve this site for the greater good

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Lately I have found this community to be very close-minded and unaccepting of any good feature changes. It is like a local-government allowing people to vote, only to later make a decision on their own merit entirely. In other words, it's like talking to a wall. I have outlined some features that should be changed and have made them clear as follows:

1.Participating in chat should only require 5 points.

2.Blocking of users from certain IPs/IP ranges should never be automatic; instead; always manual.

3.Commenting on any question/answer on the site should only require 10 points.

If you wish to prove that you're open-minded as a community, I challenge you to make one of the latter changes active within the next two weeks. If you wish to prove to me that you still continue to refuse and ignore my requests, please be honest and admit the dark truth about your community as I've mentioned.

If you can't make a change nor admit your community as I've mentioned, I ask that you promise you can keep me from using this site; **actually, I dare it**. If you fail to keep that promise, I will never stop coming back, and every time I come back and let you know it, that's a loss of face value and reputation for this entire community and what it stands for. I am here to only prove the facts. If I'm gone, I **can't** prove them.

Make me leave and prove you are right. If I keep coming back, you can't stop me nor retain face value. Your community will be gradually exposed for what it is, and you will be liars who shall live in shame.

What's it going to be? If this question is simply deleted, I'll just come back and open it again, unless you can prove me wrong. If you can't prove me wrong, we all know what that proves, don't we?

Comment: No, no, no. It's just that your ideas are bad and you haven't thought them through enough, let alone put in enough effort to look up previous discussions about these issues on [meta.se].

Comment: If you had, you'd see that it is **not possible** for a single site to implement such things; the moderators of an individual community such as this one don't decide on those things. This, to me, already proves that your posts are not worth more than to be ignored. That's what I'll stick to from now on, sorry!

Comment: Though I'm tempted to bring up a certain other physics community and show you how tame some consider us here on Stack Exchange to be compared with this other community, I think I'll avoid it. People here are actually quite nice to new users and beginners wishing to learn more; I don't think it's our fault if you've come away with the wrong impression. I *do* think, though, that if you followed @Danu's suggestions and visited the mother Meta, you'd realize that the issues you're bringing up have largely been discussed before, and have been settled.

Comment: This and the other two meta posts from this member are either deliberate trolling or one of the worst examples of an entitlement attitude.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to improve this site for the greater good is to provide answers to questions.

All else is secondary. Providing answers that use appropriate principles of physics to answer in a quantitative way is what makes this such a great site. Bonus marks if you can manage the *common touch* and make the answers intuitively obvious as well as rigorous. If you find you have time to agonise over the fine details of who can do what, when and to whom then you aren't answering enough questions.